# Ovearheated/burnt my copper pot, is it still usable?

Tags: burnt, copper-cookware

I burnt porridge to the bottom of my copper pot. It was too hot and it dried out so now the tin feels rough and has bubbled somewhat.

Is it still usable like this? Or will I need to get it re-tinned?

My main concern is that bits of tin will come off into the food/food will get stuck on the bottom.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

Try boiling a mixture of water and baking soda and then turn off the heat and let it sit until it cools enough to scrub. You might try 1/2 cup baking soda to a quart of water. Another trick is a baking powder paste. Same idea but more intense. Make a paste, bring to a boil only briefly and then scrub.